# Mixing threads, fork, and mutexes, what should I watch out for?

Tags: multithreading, fork, mutex

If I `fork` a process in which one thread holds a mutex, am I relatively safe if I immediately `exec` in the child? What things are safe to do in the child before I `exec`?

If the thread that executes `fork` then the child goes on to release a mutex before calling `exec` will this cause problems? What happens if I try to acquire a mutex in a child that the parent process owned before `fork` (and may or may not still own)?

Are the answers different on different platforms? I'm primarily concerned with Unix variants, and in particular Linux. But I am curious about NT. Though, of course, NT doesn't (to my knowledge) have `fork`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [pthread_atfork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_atfork.html), especially RATIONALE section, for a discussion of problems related to `fork` in multithreaded environment. It also gives a hint on what supposed to be valid before and after `fork` within a child and a parent.

*UPDATE: the RATIONALE section is non-normative, and it turned out to be in conflict with other parts of the standard. See [this defect report](https://collaboration.opengroup.org/external/pasc.org/interpretations/unofficial/db/p1003.1c/pasc-1003.1c-37.html) by Dave Butenhof for more details.*

Immediate `exec` after `fork` is supposed to be safe for any state of multithreaded program (that is, any threads holding any mutexes). As of the things possible between `fork` and `exec`, the situation is complicated:

The most important thing is that only one thread (that which called `fork`) is duplicated in the child process. Consequently, any mutex held by *another* thread at the moment of `fork` becomes locked forever. That is (assuming non-process-shared mutexes) its *copy* in the child process is locked forever, because there is no thread to unlock it.

Releasing mutex after `fork` is safe when it's possible, that is, if the `fork`ing thread *owns* the mutex in the first place. That's how `pthread_atfork` handlers usually work: locking mutexes before `fork`, unlocking in child *and* unlocking in parent.

As of acquiring a mutex that the process owned before fork (remember, we discuss a *copy* in the child's address space): if it was *owned* by a `fork`ing thread, it's recursive locking (works for `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE`); if it was owned by another thread, it remains locked forever and can't be reacquired.

By registering appropriate `pthread_atfork` handlers, third-party libraries can provide a guarantee of being safe to use between `fork` and `exec`. (I would expect it mostly from programming language runtimes, not for general purpose libraries).

---

After some more research, I would recommend to avoid relying *in any way* on `pthread_atfork`, and doing nothing but async-signal-safe calls between `fork` and `exec` (abandoning `fork`/`exec` for `posix_spawn` would be even better).

The problem is, `fork` itself can be invoked in signal handler. It precludes any nontrivial use of `pthread_atfork`, even if its RATIONALE explicitly mentions unlocking mutexes and recreating threads (!) in a child process.

I think that a "grey area" of different possible interpretations remains:

1. For `pthread_atfork` handlers in a program which is *known* to never call `fork` in a signal handler.
2. For non-pthread-atfork actions happening around the `fork` call which is *not* in a signal handler.

But it's crystal clear which reading is to be used for portable applications.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to exec() after fork() provided the mutex is owned by the program that will get replaced by the exec().  If the mutex is part of a library and is protecting a resource that must be accessed serially then it should call pthread_atfork() to register callbacks:

1. A function that gets called prior to the fork itself and in the context of the thread that makes the fork() system call.  Typically this function will grab the lock on mutexes that protect critical sections, thereby guaranteeing that during the fork no thread is inside a critical section
2. A function to be called in the context of the thread invoking fork(), after the child process has been created but before the fork() system call returns.  This function can then unlock the mutexes in the parent process.
3. A function to be called in the context of the thread of the child process if/when the process forks - it gets called after the child process has been created but before the fork() system call returns. The child process can then unlock its copy of the mutex.

The POSIX standard limits the type of system calls that are allowed after a fork() and before an exec() to so called async-signal-safe system calls.  Creating a thread isn't explicitly listed as an async-signal-safe system call, therefore POSIX doesn't allow a child process to create threads after a fork() and before exec().  Ironically, unlocking a mutex isn't explicitly listed as an async-signal-safe system call either, and thereofre isn't strictly allowed after a fork() in the child process if the intention of the fork() is to then exec() - probably an oversight in the standard.