# Do pthread mutexes in a single-threaded process need to be re-initialized on fork()?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, fork, posix

## Preamble

The marked "dupe" above does **not** answer my question, as it involves the safety of forking with threads in use. I am not generating threads in my code, and am more concerned with the validity of `pthread_mutex_t` structs and their internals registered with the OS when a `fork()` occurs[.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597893/specifically-how-does-fork-handle-dynamically-allocated-memory-from-malloc)  ie: **Are the mutexes re-created on `fork()` within the child process, or do children just have a valid (or invalid) shallow copy of the parent's mutex internals?**

---

## Background

I have an audio/hardware handling library that wraps some DSP functions with a simple API using a recursive `pthread_mutex_t`. The reason it is a recursive mutex is because some API functions call other API functions in turn, and I want to make sure only a single thread ever enters the critical section per instance of the library. So, the code would look like so:

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;

void read() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    // ...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void write() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    // ...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void toggle() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    read();
    // ...
    write();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

---

## Question

If a user application uses my library, and the application issues the `fork()` call, does the child process's instance of my library need to have its instance of the mutex re-initialized? I know child processes don't inherit threads, and a specific mutex initialization flag needs to be used if I want the two processes to truly share the mutex (can't recall what the flag is) or I have to make use of `mmap` IIRC. But is the mutex instance used by the child valid (ie: does `fork()` duplicate the internal values, but they aren't valid anymore, or is a new mutex initialized with the OS)? **I don't want the child and parent process to share a mutex when a `fork()` occurs, but I want to make sure the client is using a valid mutex handle.**

Note: I can guarantee that the mutex will **not** be locked when the `fork()` call is issued.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing threads, fork, and mutexes, what should I watch out for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407544/mixing-threads-fork-and-mutexes-what-should-i-watch-out-for)

Comment: If you are not using threads, then why do you need a `pthread_mutex_t` in the first place?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: It's a library that might be used in a multi-threaded process or a single-threaded process.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik caf called it. :)

Comment: @All Thank you for the in-depth answers. This was very informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrt. POSIX, I agree with [caf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39813673/1475978), but fortunately in Linux the semantics *are* defined.

From the Linux [`man 2 fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) man page:

> The child process is created with a single thread—the one that called fork().  The entire virtual address space of the parent is replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes, condition variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems that this can cause.

So, in Linux, if the mutexes are unlocked, they do not need to be reinitialized after a `fork()`.

---

More importantly, POSIX defines the same for semaphores; that

> Any semaphores that are open in the parent process shall also be open in the child process.

which means you could replace your recursive mutexes with semaphores; just replace your code with

```
#include <semaphore.h>

static sem_t  my_lock;

static void my_lock_init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void my_lock_init(void) {
    sem_init(&my_lock, 0, 1U);
}

void my_read() {
    sem_wait(&my_lock);

    // ...

    sem_post(&my_lock);
}

void my_write() {
    sem_wait(&my_lock);

    // ...

    sem_post(&my_lock);
}

void toggle() {
    sem_wait(&my_lock);

    // ...
    my_read();
    // ...
    my_write();
    // ...

    sem_post(&my_lock);
}
```

Reinitializing an already initialized semaphore leads to undefined behaviour. This means that the above works, if you somehow can prove that `fork()` never occurs between your code doing the first `sem_wait(&my_lock)` and last `sem_post(&my_lock)`.

The problem is that it is usually impossible to prove that in a multithreaded program, none of the other threads is executing any of the above functions when another thread does the `fork()`.

---

In Linux, with kernel 2.6 or later, and GNU C library version 2.5 or later, pthreads is based on NPTL, and pthread locking primitives are implemented on top of [`futex()` syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html).

The kernel is only aware of a futex when a thread is blocked or waiting on them. The rest of the time, the futex is just a normal data structure. (The kernel uses the address of the futex to tell them apart; addresses to shared memory are treated specially.)

This means that when futexes are used, you can re-init your mutex safely after a `fork()`, as long as your own code does not do the forking while holding the mutex.

As an example -- and remember, only for Linux 2.6 or later, and GNU C library 2.5 or later:

```
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_mutex_t  my_lock = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;

static void my_reinit(void)
{
    my_lock = (pthread_mutex_t)PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
}

static void my_init(void) __attribute__((constructor (65535)));
static void my_init(void)
{
    pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, my_reinit);
}

void my_read()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&my_lock);

    // ...

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_lock);
}

void my_write()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&my_lock);

    // ...

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_lock);
}

void toggle() 
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&my_lock);

    // ...
    my_read();
    // ...
    my_write();
    // ...

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_lock);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Note: I can guarantee that the mutex will **not** be locked when the `fork()` call is issued.

To guarantee that, it means you are [as you stated] *not* using threads. Otherwise, you *can't* guarantee that. So, I agree with Sam. You don't need to use a mutex.

If you *were* using threads, you probably want to do `pthread_create` instead of `fork` so that the mutex would get released "naturally" [by the holding thread].

A pthread mutex has *no* validity/meaning when you `fork`. It requires a shared address space, which after you fork, you no longer have. So, the safe bet is to reinit the mutex in the child. But, this mutex no longer operates with the parent process or its thread siblings. The init is just to prevent the child from blocking if the forking thread was *not* the mutex owner.

To lock between *threads*, use `pthread_mutex_*`. To lock between *processes*, use SysV semaphores, or posix semaphores.

Based on your pthread mutex usage in your code sample, I suspect that you want to have exclusive access to the audio device for the duration of a given API call.

If you don't use threads, you already have that *without* a mutex. When you add forking, the mutex doesn't work, so you want the [named] semaphore instead [and you'll have to implement your own wrappers because, IIRC, `sem_wait` et. al. don't do recursion]

Comment: The question is about a library, which might be used in a multi-threaded process (in which case the author wants to ensure that only one thread is executing within the library at a time) or might be used in a single-threaded process, in which case the mutexes are unnecessary but harmless.  The author also states that they don't care about exclusion between multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

A close reading of POSIX suggests that it's undefined:

- [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) says it creates an exact *copy* of the process;
- [Synchronization Object Copies and Alternative Mappings](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_09) says that *The effect of referring to a copy of the object when locking, unlocking, or destroying it is undefined.*

If you agree with this reading then the easiest solution is to avoid using the mutexes at all in the single-threaded case.  You could require the library user to link against either a multi-threaded version of the library or a single-threaded one that has #ifdef'd out the synchronisation, depending on their use case.  Alternatively, instead of calling `pthread_mutex_lock()` / `pthread_mutex_unlock()` yourself you could allow the user to provide lock / unlock callbacks that your library calls - single-threaded code would just provide empty callbacks.